# Create Swift Package from React Native

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm looking for a way (if there is one) to create a swift package / module from a React Native app.

What I want to achieve:
Having a single main swift app,
Having multiple "sub-apps", developed in react native, which an be imported into the swift app (without the whole react native setup in there).

Is this possible?

Comment: Your title/ question is not your desired outcome, because Swift Packages are specifically Swift code which doesn't have UI, not UI components which can run separately or React Native applications. You're looking to embed multiple React Native apps into a single iOS app. You can start by reading [Integration with Existing Apps](https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps), but this is an uncommon request, and you will face teething issues. You can also try one React Native app embedded within your iOS app, re-using it across the app when needed.